# Github pages : how to deploy my Symfony2 app?

Tags: symfony, github

I have a Symfony2 repo in Github, and I want to host it as a Github page. My app deals also with a MySQL database. I want to know if there's a way to deploy such an app.

I have already followed the instructions on Github Pages Help, but all I get when I put the address of my page is a "Hello World" page (the index.html) that I created as it says.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GitHub Pages only serves static content. You cannot run PHP, MySQL, or any other server side technology with GitHub Pages.